# UIButton or UIBarButtonItem didn't response well on iPhone 6s and 6s plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bonus"
                                                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                target:self
                                                                action:@selector(clickRightBarItem:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarItem;
```

I just use the system UIBarButtonItem and some UIButtons on other views,it's normal on any other iPhones except 6s and 6s plus.
On 6s and 6s plus, you should tap very very very gentle,then it responses.
So does anybody know about it?

Answer (score 0):

Get it.
The reason is that I use a category somewhere and it effects all the buttons.(UIButton+NMCategory).
The category override the touch response method,and it does not handle well.